# Is this a race condition in matlab?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, race-condition

The title says it all. I was wondering if the following code is prone to a race condition.

```
classdef Foo < handle
    properties
        value = true
    end

    methods
        function toggle(o, ~, ~)
            o.value = ~o.value;
        end
    end
end

function main
    foo = Foo;
    uicontrol('style', 'pushbutton', 'callback',@foo.toggle);
    drawnow

    %// Endless loop which gets broken up by a button press
    while foo.value
        pause(1)
    end

    %// What happens if I press the button twice, really fast? There
    %// is no external function called between here and the previous
    %// while loop.
    if foo.value
        error('Race')
    else
        fprintf('\nWe made it\n')
    end
```

Am I save from the race condition since everything happens in the event dispatch thread? Is the same still true if I play with `Interruptible` and `BusyAction` property of the button? I found the [matlab help](http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2012a/techdoc/ref/uicontrol_props.html#bqxohrx) quite confusing.

In case it matters I'm using R2012a.

Comment: Typically Matlab has just the main computation thread and the UI event dispatch thread. It is possible to add additional threads but entails something like invoking Java threads from Matlab.  Is that the scenario of concern?

Comment: @paisanco. Thanks for your comment. No, the only undocumented feature used is jbox (http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/rich-matlab-editbox-contents/). Furthermore I do not use the parallel computing toolbox or batch jobs.